# admin area as a module or sub controller folder?

Tags: yii

I'm wondering which option is better; create a normal folder under controllers folder or create a module called 'admin' with submodules in it, such as 'comment' and 'user', and why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use any of the two options you mention. I have two layouts, one for the admin area and one for the public page. Using the same controller, for the admin pages (admin, create, update, etc) i set template to my admin template. For the rest, y use the other template

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your goals. If you want to create in-line admin area, the best way is to create two separate layouts. If you want to create classic admin area, then better to use separate module. You can use subcontroller only if your admin area is tiny.

Answer (score 1):

When using the default gii code generator with CRUD, it automatically generates an admin action in the controller and corresponding admin view file for us. For example, '/post/admin', so in order to use this feature without changing the gii template or anything else, I world prefer to create an action named '/site/admin' or an admincontroller which help render those admin view files together.